# How mock the model without connection database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mocking, laravel-6, phpunit

I try to test the method `index()` of the controller. In this method, there's a model.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{        
     public function index()
     {
        return User::all();
     }
}
```

In the test class, I have the following.

```
class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIndex():void
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->make();
        $mock = Mockery::mock(User::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('all')->andReturn($user);
        $this->app->instance('User', $mock);
        $response = $this->json('GET', 'api/users');
        dd($response->getContent()); // error : [2002] Connection refused
    }

}
```

When I run the test I have an error with the connection to the database. This is weird because I have mocked the model which would mean that I don't need to establish a connection to the database. How can I solve this error?

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`
>   where `users`.`deleted_at` is null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to mock a static call with the approach for mocking a function call to an object instance. Mocking static function calls is not straight forward, it can be done with aliasing, but is not recommended.

A simple approach is to simple wrap your logic in a service and mock it.

```
class UserService {

    public function all(): Collection {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

Now you mock code should look like this.

```
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $mock = Mockery::mock(UserService::class);
    // Teoretically all method will return Eloquent Collection, but should be fine 
    $mock->shouldReceive('all')->andReturn(collect($user));
    $this->app->instance(UserService::class, $mock);
```

When using the `container` and replacing instances, it is very dependent you get these mocked classes out with the `container` and not the `new` keyword. Therefor the controller should look something similar to this.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /** @var UserService **/
    private $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService) {
        // load userService from the container as the mocked instance on tests
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->userService->all();
    }
}
```

The final note, i have over multiple projects been a main driver of testings, code coverage etc. it is way easier to create tests by having the database there, either use `sqlite` or have a `docker` environment provide the database for you. Testing without is more a hurdle than to provide anything significant of value. Speed is crucial in your testing approach, because there is gonna be a lot of it and it is better to do it quickly then to skip it due to time pressure and mocking all db calls is gonna be hard.

Comment: Thank you, to use the controller should I do a dependency injection ([like here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container))? @mrhn

Comment: To use the controller can you elaborate? The controller will always be loaded with dependency injection through the router :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I was looking on google for how to do the dependency injection through the router.